# А почему именно голубые?

Tags: сленг

Ни для кого не секрет, что лиц нетрадиционной ориентации называют в просторечии "голубыми". Причем, мне попадался этот вариант как в русском языке, так и в английском. Но почему именно такое слово (и теперь оказался скомпрометирован красивый цвет)?

Я предполагаю, что это связано с тем, в роддоме "конверты" с мальчиками украшают голубыми ленточками (кстати, тоже интересен принцип выбора цвета).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно прочитать здесь: [Этимология слова "голубой"](http://irc.lv/qna/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE) Очень интересная статья. В статье рассматриваются версии различных авторов.
<<Так, одним из первых, попытавшись раскрыть этимологию этого слова, был корреспондентом радио Би-би-си в Нью-Йорке. Как отмечают авторы этой статьи, В. Козловский не дает прямую этимологизацию термина, как предполагают некоторые современные исследователи, а лишь высказывает несмелое предположение о родственности английского термина blueribbon («голубая лента»), который в американском тюремном сленге конца XIX  начала ХХ вв. означал пассивного гомосексуала, с современным русским сленгизмом>>.

<<Во-первых, упомянутое английское словосочетание в предложенном В. Козловским контексте употреблялось крайне редко и ограниченно. Буквально означая «приз, полученный победителем в каком-либо спортивном состязании», оно имело довольно слабую гомосексуальную коннотацию и использовалось лишь с шутливым оттенком для обозначения «пассивного педераста» как «награды» в борьбе за право обладания им среди заключенных  активных гомосексуалов.

Во-вторых, никогда голубой цвет не был цветом педерастии в советской тюрьме. Со времен ГУЛАГа таким цветом считался красный, и понятно почему. Цвет коммунистической идеологии, противопоставляемой идеям «воровского братства», опускался тем самым на самое дно тюремной иерархии. Для примера можно привести словосочетание «красная косынка», употреблявшееся для тюремного обозначения пассивного гомосексуала или выражение «колхоз, Красный петух» для обозначения отряда в колонии, целиком состоящего из пассивных педерастов. Об этом явлении пишет и Л. С. Клейн <<...в современной нашей тюрьме (я знаю это по личному опыту) красный цвет считается цветом педерастии, так что его старательно избегают все остальные. От трусов, маек, даже зубных щеток красного цвета все отказываются>>. 
Далее: <<...Ареал первоначального распространения термина был очень узким и ограничивался гомосексуальной субкультурой центра Москвы, то есть рамками так называемой «штриховой элиты» — сообщества гомосексуалов, группирующегося в сквере перед Большим театром. В этой среде и следует, как мы полагаем, искать корни слова>>.

<<По нашему мнению, первоначальной формой было существительное «голубь (также как и общеупотребительное значение слова «голубой» (т. е. «имеющий цвет отлива оперения голубя») произошло, по мнению многих этимологов, от слова «голубь», хотя, справедливости ради, можно заметить, что некоторые исследователи имеют и противоположную точку зрения (см. подробнее у М. Фасмера [12])).

Опираясь на московский гомосексуальный фольклор, мы можем реконструировать такую форму как первичную, по той причине, что впервые она упоминается несколько раньше, чем производный от нее термин «голубой» в значении «гомосексуал». Более того, понятна первичность именно существительного для обозначения гомосексуала как одушевленной категории и вторичность прилагательного «голубой» в значении «гомосексуальный». Таким существительным, по нашему мнению, могло быть только слово "голубь".

Постоянные посетители уже упомянутого скверика у Большого театра часто назывались не только «голубями, но «голубками», «голубарями» и даже «голубцами», а позже и сам скверик (именовавшийся также «Штрихом (как предполагается, от формы немецкого глагола streichen ходить, гулять)) получил название «голубятня» или «голубика»>>.

<<Еще одним аргументом в пользу первичности сленгизма «голубь» могут послужить переиначенные строки популярной советской песни, написанной в 1951 г. поэтом М. Л. Матусовским для кинофильма «Мы за мир» на музыку И. О. Дунаевского – «Летите, голуби», приписываемые другому известному композитору, Никите Богословскому (Цит. по А. Щуплову [14]):

Летите, голуби, летите!

Для вас нигде преграды нет.

Хоть всю столицу обосрите.

Вас не обидит Моссовет!

Здесь первая строка ни что иное, как предупреждение гомосексуалам о приближающейся на них облаве со стороны милиции или КГБ (зафиксированное в лексикографических источниках), что было весьма актуально в советское время. Громкое пение этой песни (разумеется, со словами оригинала и на его мотив) в скверике служило кодовым сигналом для собравшихся в нем гомосексуалов о готовящемся нападении. Заметим, что пик популярности песни «Летите, голуби приходится на конец 1950-х  начало 1960-х гг. — т. е. на то время, когда о «голубых» еще никто не слышал>>.

<<В заключение отметим также, что в настоящее время термин goluboy (в английской транскрипции) приобрел неожиданную популярность в Австралии (особенно в Сиднее), что связано с наличием одновременно и крупной русскоязычной общины в стране и городе, и довольно значительного гей-сообщества. Австралийцы воспринимают русский термин goluboy как искаженное английское gal-boy  «мальчик-девочка» (здесь простонародное gal = girl), т. е. «женоподобный гомосексуал» и применяют его в этом значении>>.

Гусляр, Вы совершенно правы. В английском языке слово blue употребляется именно в тех значениях, которые привели Вы. То же самое говорят и авторы этой статьи. Вообще для обозначения данного понятия, английский использует другие слова.

Comment: @Серж, уж послали так послали!.. Если не затруднит, перескажите, пожалуйста, содержание.

Comment: @Серж . Что касается "красного цвета" в советской "зоне" , то мне один очень компетентный "работник"  рассказывал , что на личных делах "неисправимых" уголовников проводилась красная полоса . Это был учётный символ в "зоне" (и , именно , в "зоне") . Возможно , что в разные годы смысл этой красной полосы на личных делах варьировался , и могло быть такое , что красная полоса на личном деле могла означать и педераста . Эта публика , в сущности , тоже - неисправимая . Советую уточнить этот вопрос у ментов , прежде , чем говорить об антисоветском менталитете советской зоны .

Comment: Я ничего не говорю, я лишь привожу цитату. А что касается самих ментов, то скажу: я живу в Армении, вряд ли какой-то армянин-милиционер будет знать о таких подробностях.

Comment: @Серж . Ну ... я немножко неправильно выразился , что попало в ваш адрес . Пожалуйста , не будьте слишком обидчивы .

Answer (score 2):

Приведите пример данного значения в английском языке. На сколько я знаю, самые близкие к этой теме значения: "непристойный", "скабрёзный", "пошлый", "порнографический". Никакой четкой педерастии.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить на рассмотрение ашкеназскую версию. На языке идиш **גאָלב**, побуквенно **Г**-**О**-**Л**-**Б**, означает <<**ЗОЛОТО**>>. (См. идиш переводчик по интернет-ссылке [Идиш язык онлайн](http://w2mem.com/langrevers/yi) и идиш-алфавит / копирование букв на следующей странице / [Алфавит языка идиш](http://www.languages-study.com/yiddish/alefbeys.html).) Насколько известно, в былые времена (как сейчас — не знаю) пассивные педерасты зарабатывали большие деньги, и мне приходилось слышать об этой особенности "голубого" ремесла. Вспомним и одесский песенный фольклор — "*На дерибасовской открылася пивная*...". Там присутствуют слова:

...Две полудевочки, а с ними *полумальчик*,
Который ездил побираться в город Нальчик.
А возвращался на машине марки форда
И шил костюмы элегантно, как у лорда.

Тюремный сленг (феня), а равно и сленг антиморальной субкультуры формировались под прямым влиянием еврейской уголовщины и ашкеназской богемы .